# How to organize interfaces and implementations in WPF MVVM application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, architecture

I'm working on WPF MVVM project which contains following projects,

- Domain,
- ViewModels,
- Infrastructure,
- Views

and for example I need `IFileService` that provide some operations with file and doesn't contains any business logic, I'm sure that the implementation of this interface FileService will be in Infrastructure project, but I have question where to put the `IFileService` interface

I need to use this interface in ViewModels project, if I will put it in this projects its mean that Infrastructure will have reference on ViewModels that is not good I think, if I will put it in Domain which contains business related classes the same.

Help me what is the best to organize structure and references between projects and where to put interfaces like `IFileService`?

Comment: you can implement interface in Infrastructure project , interface will also available in viewmodels, when you refer Infrastructure class instances

Comment: @Arun I think your comment should be  answer for my question. I think it is good

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, why not creating an additional project like `DAL` or `DataLayer`? It provides the model classes, which I'm also missing in your listing. You could also put the interface `IFileService` there although I would prefer working with `DataProviders` or `Repositories` (that's my prefered option), so that the VMs are not aware from where the data was loaded.

IMHO The project `Infrastructure` shouldn't not contain any sofisticated logic. I would put some useful methods and classes there and keep it as simple and clean as possible, so that it could be referenced everywhere. Probably, you won't even need it.

Comment: All Repositories implementations in Infrastructure project interfaces in IRepository in Domain, Model classes in domain as well. What do you mean DataProvider?

Comment: Ah ok. Well the `DataProvider` would be source for the data. Usual interface mechanisms. VMs would be using `IDataProvider` and a factory would instantiate the implementation behind it. - **Infrastructure** is IMHO a pretty bad name for a project containing the implementations of the repositories. It implies, at least for me, a total different content (some common methods and classes, usable everywhere in the solution). If `IRepository` is defined in `Domain`, I would call the project e.g. `DomainImplementation`. But that's my opinion. :o)

Answer (score 3):

The unique rule I use for my MVVM project is, all projects **have a reference** to my Infrastructure project and my Infrastructure project **has no reference** to my other project.

So IMHO, IFileService, and interfaces in general, should be in the Infrastructure project. Then it is up to you decide where to put the implementation. The Infrastructure project usually has very basic logic implementation and final implementation goes to a dedicated project.

The only exception I sometimes add to this rule is when I base my development on an existing MVVM framework, then Infrastructure might reference it too but I try to avoid this approach.

Comment: One more question implementation of interfaces where should be?

Comment: Well, that will really depend of the size and nature of your project. Is it small? Does it make a heavy use of IoC or reflection? There is no "one solution fits all" reply here. I would say that the more you have the need for modularity, the more you will have dedicated libraries for implementations. In case of data access implementation, having a DataAccess or DataProvider library might be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the **IFileService** interface to Infrastructure project. because this will make it available to every project as this is the core project right. and you might have diffrent implemantations e.g. syncronious file reader and asyncronius file reader. so the implemantation could go into your modules or ViewModels.

Comment: My Infrastructure project contains implementations of Repositories which works with Database, if I will put IFileService in this project I will have reference in Domain on Infrastruture project I think it is not good

Comment: yes you are right. you can switch from Infrastructure to Domain.

Comment: And you think that is good to put implementation of FileService which works with file in ViewModels?

Comment: its upto your business logic if you are sure that you won't have multiple implemantations of IFileService you can put it in one global place. eighter viewmodels or in Infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks for answer ok I will put interface in Infrastructure where should I put implementation?